# How to get rid of double quotes in hash keys with dot in it

Tags: json, ruby

The problem is following, I have a json file with array of hashes
there are many hash keys with dots
example:

```
"first.key.in.hash": "value"
```

when I read file and then JSON.parse it:

```
read = File.read(filedir)
variable = JSON.parse(filedir, symbolize_names: true)
```

I get the following stored in variable:

```
:"first.key.in.hash"=>"value"
```

If there is no dot in a key, then everything is fine.
How to solve this? Is there any solutions? (I must not remove dots from json file)

Comment: You cannot remove the quotes in that case because that'd end up being a syntax error; `:first.key.in.hash` is not a valid symbol, while `:"first.key.in.hash"` is perfectly valid a hash key. Perhaps you meant to do something else? What's the purpose of this?

Comment: Adding to the upper comment, the reason your key is forced to have a quote it is because ruby has to know a way to identify a method call after a literal symbol, for example, a symbol calls a 'to_s' method, that would be `:symbol.to_s`, so not having a quote in your case could be interpreted as `:first.key.in.hash`, which makes ruby think you have a `:first` symbol which calls a `key` method, which calls ... and so on, and then it's exibited with quotes to avoid any confusions (imo)

Comment: You could just transform them after the fact e.g. `variable = JSON.parse(filedir).transform_keys! {|k| k.gsub(".","_").to_sym }` which will result in `{:first_key_in_hash => "value"}`

Comment: Can you clarify your question, please? I don't see any keys with quotes in them in your question. So, what are the quotes you want to get rid of?